# Xpath: how to get text in an element that is inside a tag in another tag?

Tags: xml, xpath

I need an xpath to get the text inside each of the table-row of:

```
<span class="hoverQP" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" onmouseover="ddrivetip('<div class=\'qtyPriceBorder\'><table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=\'100%\'><tr><td colspan=2 class=\'qtyPriceHeader\'>Quantity Pricing Available!</td></tr><tr class=\'qtyPriceRow\'><td>1 - 11</td><td>$63.23 ea.</td></tr><tr class=\'qtyPriceRow\'><td>12+</td><td>$60.45 ea.</td></tr></table></div>', 300);">Hover for Qty Pricing</span>
```

Formatted for easier reading:

```
<span class="hoverQP" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" onmouseover="ddrivetip('
    <div class=\'qtyPriceBorder\'>
        <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=\'100%\'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2 class=\'qtyPriceHeader\'>Quantity Pricing Available!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class=\'qtyPriceRow\'>
                <td>1 - 11</td>
                <td>$63.23 ea.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class=\'qtyPriceRow\'>
                <td>12+</td>
                <td>$60.45 ea.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>'
    , 300
);">Hover for Qty Pricing</span>
```

Page URL: http://www.skygeek.com/phillips-xc-20w50-aircraft-oil.html

the above span tag appears under: .//*[@class='bundleItemTable']/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]

Comment: Putting HTML in a `onmouseover` attribute feels like the wrong way to solve this problem.

Comment: Please can you provide a bit more detail on what you've tried / how you're accessing this?  It looks like the data you're after isn't XML, but is the text value of an `onmouseover` attribute, which happens to contain some HTML.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no HTML table in your `onmouseover` attribute. There is a string with some Javascript code in there. Inside this Javascript code there is another string, which contains angle brackets (to the untrained eye it may even look like HTML, but it isn't. It's a string with angle brackets that lives in your Javascript engine when the page is loaded). There is no way you can get any information out of that with XPath.

Comment: What data are you looking for exactly? Price and rating?